# Linux, C: Accumulate data from multiple threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, networking

I have an application which plays a network server role, and will pthread_create multiple threads and each thread will listen on a particular TCP port and accept multiple TCP socket connections.
Now, after some time for example, 60 seconds, all network clients (TCP socket clients) have been closed (but my application is still running those threads and listening on those ports), how do I collect data (such as total_bytes received) from those threads created by my application?

One solution I currently used is: in each socket accept(), when new data arrives, the corresponding thread will update a static variable with pthread_mutex_t. But I suspect this is low efficiency and waste time by the mutex.

Is there any lock-free way to do this? 
If there any solution of "per_cpu" counters just like it is used in network driver/without lock/mutex?
Or, I don't update the Receiver_Total_Bytes when receiving n bytes from socket (read()). Instead, I keep calculate the total bytes within the thread. But the question is, how do I get the total bytes number from a un-finished thread?

===sudo code===

```
register long Receiver_Total_Bytes = 0;
static pthread_mutex_t Summarizer_Mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void add_server_transfer_bytes(register long bytes )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &Summarizer_Mutex );
    Receiver_Total_Bytes += bytes;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &Summarizer_Mutex );
}

void reset_server_transfer_bytes( )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &Summarizer_Mutex );
    Receiver_Total_Bytes = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &Summarizer_Mutex );
}
```

Then in socket read:

```
if((n = read(i, buffer, bytes_to_be_read)) > 0) {
    ............
    add_server_transfer_bytes(n);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to allocate a structure for each thread, and have that structure include the desired counters, say `connections` and `total_bytes`, at least.

The thread itself should increment these using atomic built-ins:

```
__sync_fetch_and_add(&(threadstruct->connections), 1);
__sync_fetch_and_add(&(threadstruct->total_bytes), bytes);
```

or

```
__atomic_fetch_add(&(threadstruct->connections), 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
__atomic_fetch_add(&(threadstruct->total_bytes), bytes, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
```

These are slightly slower than non-atomic operations, but the overhead is very small, if there is no contention. (In my experience, cacheline ping-pong -- when different CPUs try to access the variable at the same time -- is a significant risk and a real-world cause for slowdown, but here the risk is minimal. At worst, only the current thread and the main thread may access the variables at the same time. Of course, the main thread should not calculate the summaries too often; say, once or twice a second should be enough.)

Because the structure is allocated in the main thread, the main thread can also access the counters. To collect the totals, it'll use a loop, and inside the loop,

```
overall_connections += __sync_fetch_and_add(&(threadstruct[thread]->connections), 0);
overall_total_bytes += __sync_fetch_and_add(&(threadstruct[thread]->total_bytes), 0);
```

or

```
overall_connections += __atomic_load_n(&(threadstruct[thread]->connections));
overall_total_bytes += __atomic_load_n(&(threadstruct[thread]->total_bytes));
```

See the GCC manual for further information on the [__atomic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) and [__sync](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fsync-Builtins) built-in functions. Other C compilers like Intel CC also provide these -- or at least used to; the last time I verified this was a few years ago. The __sync ones are older (and more widely supported in older compiler versions), but the __atomic ones reflect the memory models specified in C11, so are more likely to be supported by future C compilers.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing: how do I reset the counter to 0? I tried this, but it does not work:  __atomic_store_n( &(streams[t]->bytes), 0, __ATOMIC_RELEASE );

Comment: @SimonXiao: If you want to read-and-clear it, use `total_bytes += __atomic_fetch_and(&(streams[t]->bytes), 0, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);`. I recommend using the most strict requirements, and only relax them after you have the scheme working, and can think about and check which requirements are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your concerns are warranted. The worst thing you can do here is to use mutex as suggested in another answer. Mutexes preempt threads, so they really are multithreaders worst enemy. The other thing which might come to mind is to use atomic operations for incrementing (also mentioned in the same answer). Terrible idea indeed! Atomic operations perform very poor under contention (atomic increment is a actually a loop, which will try to incrememnt until succeeds). Since in the case described I imagine the conention will be high, atomics will behave bad.

The other problem with atomics and mutexes a like is that enforce memory ordering and impose bariers. Not a good thing for performance!

The real solution to the question, is, of course, having each thread using it's own private counter. It is not per-cpu, it is per thread. Once the threads are done, those counters can be accumulated.

Comment: If the threads use atomics to increment their counters, then the main thread can accumulate the summaries every now and then, say once or twice per second, without any measurable performance impact.

Comment: Thanks. per-thread counter sound good, but the question is, how I do access each thread's counter when this thread is not finished/returned?

Comment: @SimonXiao: That's what my answer is all about.

Comment: Yes, @NominalAnimal provided an answer for this. Since those counter are per thread, the atomic contention problem will not be an issue.

Comment: You are assuming that the counter is a point of contention. This might be true, or not at all. No information in this regard has been given.

Comment: @usr Enough information is given. First, author worries about performance. It is good indicator for me. Second, by the nature of the functions  which count bytes transferred over socket, I figure they will be pretty contentous.

Comment: Yeah, you might be right. If uncontended a mutex op is almost as cheap as an interlocked op. Depends on the amount of contention. Let's see what the OP says about this. I wonder if he measured anything.